# Highlighting all items inside a volume in editor view

Tags: map-editor, world-editor

I want to highlight all items inside of an area in editor view like the picture below. I'm writing a procedural generator and want to show where the user is going to draw. I could do this in a post processing effect on the depth buffer I imagine, but I'm just curious if there was a way to use something like a decal projector or something like that procedurally without adding game objects.

[image: Example]

Comment: It looks like you forgot to tell us about your tech stack. Are you working in an existing engine or your own tech, in what language or with what libraries?

Comment: I'm using unity, URP. I'm looking at doing this with toggleable post process effect and depth texture. Anything within a sphere of a ray cast by depth will be a color.

Comment: Be sure to edit your question so it actually includes critical details like those.